# SHA 1 implementation in PHP and .Net

Tags: php, .net, encryption, encoding, character-encoding

I'm working on a project(PHP Based) in which I need to compute SHA1, I'm using this line of code to generate SHA1 in PHP.

```
$da = file_get_contents("payload.txt");
echo sha1($da);
```

and this is the code for the .Net

```
private static string GetSHA1(string text)
        {
            UnicodeEncoding UE = new UnicodeEncoding();
            byte[] hashValue;
            byte[] message = UE.GetBytes(text);

            SHA1Managed hashString = new SHA1Managed();
            string hex = "";

            hashValue = hashString.ComputeHash(message);
            foreach (byte x in hashValue)
            {
                hex += String.Format("{0:x2}", x);
            }
            return hex;
        }
```

But I'm confused because both of languages generate different results, I'm not provide any salt in both of them(as I don't know what to use in salt b/c the api didn't defined that)

I also need to work on RSA after that(I've a key for the encryption)
Also Can anyone tell, does these algorithms differ due to languages or any thing I'm missing???

Need some experts opinion on this

this is the whole Algorithm to generate SHA1 and RSA encryption

```
<?php
class MyEncryption
{

    public $pubkey = '...public key here...';
    public $privkey = '...private key here...';

    public function encrypt($data)
    {
        if (openssl_private_encrypt($data, $encrypted, $this->pubkey))
            $data = base64_encode($encrypted);
        else
            throw new Exception('Unable to encrypt data. Perhaps it is bigger than the key size?');

        return $data;
    }

    public function decrypt($data)
    {
        if (openssl_private_decrypt(base64_decode($data), $decrypted, $this->privkey))
            $data = $decrypted;
        else
            $data = '';

        return $data;
    }
}

$enc = new MyEncryption();
$enc->pubkey = file_get_contents("server.key");
$payload = file_get_contents("payload1.txt");//payload1.txt contain xml data
$hashRes = sha1($payload,true);
echo $enc->encrypt($hashRes);


?>
```

Thanks alot

Comment: I've tested both languages generate different results

Comment: You don't have to apply a salt when hashing text. What are you trying to achieve with the hashing?

Comment: I'm just trying to acheive hash using SHA1 then encrypt it using RSA

Comment: But the generated result is not right

Comment: You don't need a salt then, but normally the hash and encrypt with private key, using PKCS#1 padding is seens as a single operation to the cryptographic binary. Now, do you want to sign binary data, or do you want to sign a String? Only in the latter case do you need encoding?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's your `UnicodeEncoding`. PHP doesn't know anything about encodings, so your string simply contains all the bytes that the file does, 1:1. In .NET however, if you read the file as text, it will assume some encoding (typically UTF-8, if you don't specify otherwise) and then converts it to the internal representation, and in the end you convert it to UTF-16 and hash **those** bytes - which are probably nothing like the original at bytes all, unless the original also was UTF-16. And even if it was UTF-16, it might have included the Byte-Order-Mark, which `UnicodeEncoding.GetBytes()` doesn't. And even if it didn't, the original string might not have been normalized, and you might have normalized it somewhere along the way (you don't show us the code where you read it), and the bytes will be different again. Etc.

The correct approach would be to read the whole file as a binary block of bytes (for example, with `System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes()`), and then hash those bytes directly. There's no need to involve any text encodings and conversions. And then the hashes should match.

Comment: so whats the standard, that api didn't defined any encoding

Comment: @MZubair - Just don't read it as text, if you only want to hash it! Forget the encodings!

Comment: for generating hash, I'm not encoding anything from my own, I'm encoding after the encryption, should I remove that??

Comment: @MZubair - to put it in another way - text is text; and bytes are bytes; and they are not the same thing. Text is abstract. It's a bunch of simbols, simply floating out there somewhere. There are dozens upon dozens of ways how to convert text to bytes and back again, and it's always going to be the same text, but the bytes will be different every time. So don't rely that "same text" == "same bytes". It doesn't work that way. If you need to work with bytes, work with bytes. If you need to work with text, work with text. Don't mix them.

Comment: @MZubair - in .NET you **are** encoding it, in the line where it says `UE.GetBytes(text);` You're not hashing the original bytes of the file; you're hashing the converted bytes.

Comment: Hmm, the "data" argument does make me feel this is binary data indeed. I'll vote you up.

Comment: @Vilx-Yep I know there difference, but that is in .net not PHP

Comment: that payload file contain xml data that is confidential

Comment: Hashing is not used to create confidentiality, you need encryption (e.g. using AES in CBC mode) for that. This is, e.g. present in the [XML encryption standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlenc-core/). That should be enough if you simply keep the file on disk.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried sha1(data, true)? Otherwise it will generate hexadecimals. You can also use hex2bin(sha1(data)) if it is not available on your platform. Also, UnicodeEncoding may use 2 bytes as encoding instead of one (for characters that are also in ASCII). Try UTF8Encoding instead.

Comment: No UTF8Encoding in C# or do it the other way around and encode to UTF-16 before hashing in PHP, which seems to be implied by UnicodeEncoding (leave it to M$ to incorrectly name classes): http://www.php.net/manual/en/mbstring.supported-encodings.php

Comment: As there seems to be a file in between, the encoding within the file matters as well. I do hope it is a text file? Otherwise the UnicodeEncoder would not make sense...

Comment: I think the best approach is to simply read the bytes in .NET and hash those bytes in .NET, and forget all about encodings entirely.

Comment: @Vilx-actually I need to implement it in php, I just wrote C# code to match the result, does the above code is right?