# Which comparison will go first? (c#)

Tags: c#, ternary-operator

How does it work? Which one runs first?

Given

```
int a = 100;
```

What would the following return?

```
int b = a > 5 ? a > 10 ? 10 : 5 : 0;
```

Comment: This is something you can test yourself.  Just run your code and observe the results.

Comment: Here is the result : https://dotnetfiddle.net/gVFyHg

Comment: Your question is essentially a dupe of this one, which has a good answer by Konrad Rudolph: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1763543/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rewrite what you just wrote like this:

```
a > 5 ? ( a > 10 ? 10 : 5 ) : 0
```

After all, there is no other way you could arrange the parentheses that would make sense. Therefore, the `a > 5` comparison must be tested first because if `a > 5` does not evaluate to `true`, then the second comparison is not necessary.

Comment: Your code is missing the first ?.
a > 5 ? ( a > 10 ? 10 : 5 ) : 0